# Global SRSS dataset for Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

This is kinda a nooby question. I am wondering if it is possible to dynamically populate the schema of a shared dataset(living in the reporting services server) by passing in two parameters (id and username) and to use this dataset for the reports in Report Builder 3.0.

As the tables in the database are created dynamically, there is no certain way of knowing the columns used in each table hence the need to dynamically populate the schema of the shared dataset each time.

The problem I am facing is the restriction placed on the need to specify the schema before being able to load the dataset onto the reporting services server and before being able to use it whilst designing a report in Report Builder 3.0. Is it possible to change the schema of the dataset living on the server on the fly ?